# FORMATAÇÃO DE PLANILHAS COM VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Recentemente fiz uma macro, onde ao clicar em um botão de formatação de planilhas, irá formatar todas as planilhas do meu arquivo excel. E consegui, porém gostaria de fazer uma alteração bem útil, como podem ver defini o "ultima_linha", onde o excel encontra a última linha com dados e aplica a formatação. Mas como poderia fazer nesse codigo, que também faça o mesmo para colunas? de modo que eu não precise definir OBS: "A3:H"?, gostaria que ele encontrasse a última coluna com dados e aplicasse a formatação, do mesmo jeito que o "ultima_linha" faz. Alguém poderia me ajudar??

```html
Sub formatar()

total_planilhas = Sheets.Count

'INDICE QUE PASSA POR CADA UMA DAS PLANILHAS TRABALHADA
For num_planilha = 2 To total_planilhas 'Para numero da planilha trabalhada do momento, começa com valor 1 e vai até o total de planilhas

    'Descobrir a última linha da planilha
    ultima_linha = Sheets(num_planilha).UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Vai contar quantas linhas na faixa utilizada, da sheets numero de planilha

    'Tamanho da fonte
    Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A1:H" & ultima_linha).Font.Size = 14 'Mexe no tamanho da fonte
    
    'Formatar Cabeçalho
    Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3:H3").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
    Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3:H3").Font.Color = vbWhite
    Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3:H3").Font.Bold = True
    
    'Formatar células de ARE SIS
    'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A25:H25").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
    'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A35:H35").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
    'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A40:H40").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
    'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A52:H52").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
    'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A68:H68").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
    'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A74:H74").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
    'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A84:H84").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
    
    
    'Bordas
    Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3:H" & ultima_linha).Borders.LineStyle = 1
    
    'Remover Linhas de Grade
    Sheets(num_planilha).Activate
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False 'JanelaAtiva, Mostra linhas de grade
    
    'Congelar Paineis
    Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A4").Activate
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    
    'Adiciona AutoFiltro
    Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3:H" & ultima_linha).AutoFilter
    
    'Auto-Ajuste da largura das colunas
    Sheets(num_planilha).Columns("A:H").AutoFit 'NÃO SERÁ PRECISO POIS JÁ ESTÁ APLICADO NA MACRO DE INFO


Next



End Sub
```

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da mesma maneira que você usou o **UsedRange.Rows.Count** para contar a quantidade de linhas, podemos também usar o **UsedRange.Columns.Count**, até o momento você já deve ter pensado nessa solução, e reparou que essa função nos trás um valor numérico, bem, então... É só procurar por uma maneira de transformar esse valor numérico na letra da coluna:

Declarando as variáveis:

```
Dim NumeroColuna As Long

Dim LetraColuna As String
```

Essa é a parte que pega a Coluna (em número) e transfere para Letra:

```
NumeroColuna = Sheets(num_planilha).UsedRange.Columns.Count

LetraColuna = Split(Cells(1, NumeroColuna).Address, "$")(1)
```

Tendo isso em mente, agora é só concatenar essa variável com o seu código, substituindo onde antes era a coluna(fixa) "H".

```
Sub formatar()

total_planilhas = Sheets.Count

Dim NumeroColuna As Long
Dim LetraColuna As String

'INDICE QUE PASSA POR CADA UMA DAS PLANILHAS TRABALHADA
For num_planilha = 2 To total_planilhas 'Para numero da planilha trabalhada do momento, começa com valor 1 e vai até o total de planilhas

'Descobrir a última linha da planilha
ultima_linha = Sheets(num_planilha).UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Vai contar quantas linhas na faixa utilizada, da sheets numero de planilha
NumeroColuna = Sheets(num_planilha).UsedRange.Columns.Count
LetraColuna = Split(Cells(1, NumeroColuna).Address, "$")(1)

'Tamanho da fonte
Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A1" & ":" & LetraColuna & ultima_linha).Font.Size = 14 'Mexe no tamanho da fonte

'Formatar Cabeçalho
Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3" & ":" & LetraColuna & "3").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3" & ":" & LetraColuna & "3").Font.Color = vbWhite
Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3" & ":" & LetraColuna & "3").Font.Bold = True

'Formatar células de ARE SIS
'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A25:H25").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A35:H35").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A40:H40").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A52:H52").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A68:H68").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A74:H74").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho
'Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A84:H84").Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213) 'Cor do cabeçalho


'Bordas
Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3" & ":" & LetraColuna & ultima_linha).Borders.LineStyle = 1

'Remover Linhas de Grade
Sheets(num_planilha).Activate
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False 'JanelaAtiva, Mostra linhas de grade

'Congelar Paineis
Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A4").Activate
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'Adiciona AutoFiltro
Sheets(num_planilha).Range("A3" & ":" & LetraColuna & ultima_linha).AutoFilter

'Auto-Ajuste da largura das colunas
Sheets(num_planilha).Columns("A:" & LetraColuna).AutoFit 'NÃO SERÁ PRECISO POIS JÁ ESTÁ APLICADO NA MACRO DE INFO


Next



End Sub
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: VOCÊ É UM GÊNIO, muito obrigado sério! me salvou hahah

Comment: 

Comment: Uma última dúvida, se souber me responder. É possivel fazer com que na parte de formatação, desse código adicione uma cor de cabeçalho nas linhas de determinadas palavras? Por exemplo: na minha planilha tem vários dados e queria que formatasse automaticamente, do jeito que está fazendo porém colocando cor em cada linha de cabeçalho, nessas palavras chaves por exemplo "CCD, CTC, DSC, EAC, ECC" ou necessita especificar as células? pois as vezes essas palavras poderão estar em outra célula, dependendo da planilha que aplicar a formatação

Comment: Certo, acredito que entendi parte da sua dúvida, ao encontrar algumas dessas palavras chaves, na coluna C, por exemplo, você precisa colorir todas as linhas da coluna C? ou essas palavras serão dados que serão encontrados abaixo do cabeçalho (e precisam pintar apenas a célula do respectivo cabeçalho?), Tenho quase certeza que consigo desenvolver a solução que necessita, mas só preciso entender um pouco melhor a situação mesmo...

Comment: Não, imagina que tem uma tabela, com diversos dados, e entre esses dados tem algumas linhas como se fossem cabeçalhos. Exemplo: "CCD(10), Ai embaixo tem os dados do CCD, depois se encontra dados do CTC(8) e embaixo os dados do CTC e por ai vai... Então poderia ter algum jeito da macro identificar essas palavras e colorir toda a linha em que se encontra